# Unable to Add Points of Function to Plot (gif)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, gif

I wrote this script to create a function that slides to the right and always has two points of the plot designated as the black dots:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
 \pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
 \begin{document}
 \tikzset{declare function={bellshape(\x,\mu,\sigma)=exp(-(\x-\mu)^2/(2*\sigma^2));}}
 \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
 \foreach \center in {-5,-4.9,...,5}
 {
   \begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis}[scale=3,
                   width=4cm,
                   xmin=-3, xmax=3, 
                   ymin=-.05, ymax=1.4,
                   axis line style={draw=none},
                   ]
           \addplot [only marks, samples at={-3,3}]
             {bellshape(x,\center,.5)};
           \addplot [domain=-5:5, samples=300,color=blue, name path=A]
             {bellshape(x,\center,.5)};
       \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
 }
 \end{document}
```

Which is exactly what I intended:

[image]
 But I am also trying to make one for the wave packet below.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
  \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
  \pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
  \begin{document}
  \tikzset{declare function={bellshape(\x,\mu,\sigma)=exp(-(\x-\mu)^2/(2*\sigma^2));}}
  \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
  \foreach \center in {-350,-320,...,350}
  {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[scale=3,
                    width=4cm,
                    xmin=-250, xmax=250, 
                    ymin=-1, ymax=1,
                    axis line style={draw=none},
                    ]
            \addplot [only marks, samples at={-250,250}]
            {.1*(bellshape(x,\center-100,25)+bellshape(x,\center-50,25)+bellshape(x,\     center,25)+bellshape(x,\center+50,25)+bellshape(x,\center+100,25))*sin(     deg(20*pi*x))};
            \addplot [domain=-600:600,samples=400,color=blue]
            {.1*(bellshape(x,\center-100,25)+bellshape(x,\center-50,25)+bellshape(x,\     center,25)+bellshape(x,\center+50,25)+bellshape(x,\center+100,25))*sin(     deg(20*pi*x))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \end{document}
```

I followed the same idea (put the same function of the blue line into the function for just the two black dots), but am getting no motion from the two black dots. When I tried taking the "sin" function out, the black dots move to the "bellshape" functions, so I believe the error must be with the sin function? Does anyone have any ideas of what could remedey this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! I think when copying the code something happened, you have twice `\     center` in (i.e. spurious spaces) so the code won't compile. The reason seems to be that the domains of the plots are vastly different.

Comment: The reason is very simple. You multiply the plot with the overall factor `*sin(deg(20*pi*x))`, which, evaluated at x=+-250, gives zero. In the working, first example this does not happen.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things I do not understand in your code, most importantly the parametrization of the wave packet. In your case it is a sum of Gaussians, each of which moves with the same velocity, multiplied an overall *stationary* phase. Why? In any case, this why you have the effect you observe. The `samples at` plot gets multiplied by `*sin(deg(20*pi*x))`, which is zero at `x=-250` and `x=250`.

I'd go with an arguably more physical wave packet.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{declare function={bellshape(\x,\mu,\sigma)=exp(-(\x-\mu)^2/(2*\sigma^2));
wavepacket(\x,\mu,\sigma,\k)=bellshape(\x,\mu,\sigma)*sin(\k*(\x-\mu));}}
\foreach \X in {-350,-320,...,350}
  {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%scale=3,
                    width=4cm,
                    xmin=-250, xmax=250, 
                    ymin=-1, ymax=1,
                    axis line style={draw=none},
                    ]
  \addplot [only marks, samples at={-250,250}]
            {0.1*(wavepacket(x,\X-100,25,4)+
                wavepacket(x,\X-50,25,4)+
                wavepacket(x,\X-25,25,4)+
                wavepacket(x,\X+25,25,4)+
                wavepacket(x,\X+50,25,4)+
                wavepacket(x,\X+100,25,4))};
  \addplot [domain=-250:250,samples=251,color=blue,smooth]
            {0.1*(wavepacket(x,\X-100,25,4)+
                wavepacket(x,\X-50,25,4)+
                wavepacket(x,\X-25,25,4)+
                wavepacket(x,\X+25,25,4)+
                wavepacket(x,\X+50,25,4)+
                wavepacket(x,\X+100,25,4))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{document}
```

[image]